# How do rails association methods work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

How do rails association methods work? Lets consider this example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I can do something like

```
@user = User.find(:first)
@user.articles
```

This fetches me articles belonging to that user. So far so good.

Now further I can go ahead and do a find on these articles with some conditions.

```
@user.articles.find(:all, :conditions => {:sector_id => 3})
```

Or simply declare and associations method like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles do
     def of_sector(sector_id)
       find(:all, :conditions => {:sector_id => sector_id})
     end
   end
end
```

And do

```
@user.articles.of_sector(3)
```

Now my question is, how does this `find` work on the array of `ActiveRecord` objects fetched using the association method? Because if we implement our own `User` instance method called `articles` and write our own implementation that gives us the exact same results as that of the association method, the find on the fetch array of `ActiveRecord` objects wont work.

My guess is that the association methods attach certain properties to the array of fetched objects that enables further querying using `find` and other `ActiveRecord` methods. What is the sequence of code execution in this this case? How could I validate this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How it actually works is that the association object is a "proxy object".  The specific class is [AssociationProxy](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb).  If you look at line 52 of that file, you'll see:

```
instance_methods.each { |m| undef_method m unless m =~ /(^__|^nil\?$|^send$|proxy_|^object_id$)/ }
```

By doing this, methods like `class` no longer exist on this object.  So if you call `class` on this object, you'll get method missing.  So, there a `method_missing` implemented for the proxy object that forwards the method call to the "target":

```
def method_missing(method, *args)
  if load_target
    unless @target.respond_to?(method)
      message = "undefined method `#{method.to_s}' for \"#{@target}\":#{@target.class.to_s}"
      raise NoMethodError, message
    end

    if block_given?
      @target.send(method, *args)  { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
    else
      @target.send(method, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

The target is an Array, so when you call `class` on this object, it says it's an Array, but that's just because the target is an Array, the actual class is an AssociationProxy, but you can't see that anymore.

So all the methods that you add, such as `of_sector`, get added to the association proxy, so they get called directly.  Methods like `[]` and `class` aren't defined on the association proxy, so they get sent to the target, which is an array.

To help you see how this is happening, add this to line 217 of that file in your local copy of association_proxy.rb:

```
Rails.logger.info "AssociationProxy forwarding call to `#{method.to_s}' method to \"#{@target}\":#{@target.class.to_s}"
```

If you don't know where that file is, the command `gem which 'active_record/associations/association_proxy'` will tell you.  Now when you call `class` on a AssociationProxy, you will see a log message telling you it is sending that to the target, which should make it clearer what is happening.  This is all for Rails 2.3.2 and could change in other versions.

Comment: This one `/(^__|^nil\?$|^send$|proxy_|^object_id$)/` is so jolly I'm not afraid of regexes anymore.

Answer (score 10):

As already mentioned, the active record associations create a metric buttload of convenience methods. Sure, you could write your own methods to fetch everything. But that is not the Rails Way.

The Rails Way is the culmination of two mottos. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and "Convention over Configuration". Essentially by naming things in a way that makes sense, some robust methods provided by the framework can abstract out all the common code. The code you place in your question is the perfect example of something that can be replaced by a single method call.

Where these convenience methods really shine are the more complex situations. The kind of thing involving join models, conditions, validations, etc.

To answer your question when you do something like `@user.articles.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ? ", tuesday])`, Rails prepares two SQL queries and then merges them into one. where as your version just returns the list of objects. Named scopes do the same thing, but usually don't cross model boundaries.

You can validate it by checking the SQL queries in the development.log as you call these things in the console.

So lets talk about [Named Scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) for a moment because they give a great example of how rails handles the SQL, and I think they're a simpler way to demonstrate what's going on behind the scenes, as they don't need any model associations to show off.

Named Scopes can be used to perform custom searches of a model. They can be chained together or even called through associations. You could easily create custom finders that return identical lists, but then you run into the same problems mentioned in the Question.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commentators, :through :comments, :class_name => "user"
  named_scope :edited_scope, :conditions => {:edited => true}
  named_scope :recent_scope, lambda do
    { :conditions => ["updated_at > ? ", DateTime.now - 7.days]}

  def self.edited_method
    self.find(:all, :conditions => {:edited => true})
  end

  def self.recent_method
    self.find(:all, :conditions => ["updated_at > ?", DateTime.now - 7 days])
  end
end

Article.edited_scope
=>     # Array of articles that have been flagged as edited. 1 SQL query.
Article.edited_method
=>     # Array of Articles that have been flagged as edited. 1 SQL query.
Array.edited_scope == Array.edited_method
=> true     # return identical lists.

Article.recent_scope
=>     # Array of articles that have been updated in the past 7 days.
   1 SQL query.
Article.recent_method
=>     # Array of Articles that have been updated in the past 7 days.
   1 SQL query.
Array.recent_scope == Array.recent_method
=> true     # return identical lists.
```

Here's where things change:

```
Article.edited_scope.recent_scope
=>     # Array of articles that have both been edited and updated 
    in the past 7 days. 1 SQL query.
Article.edited_method.recent_method 
=> # no method error recent_scope on Array

# Can't even mix and match.
Article.edited_scope.recent_method
=>     # no method error
Article.recent_method.edited_scope
=>     # no method error

# works even across associations.
@user.articles.edited.comments
=>     # Array of comments belonging to Articles that are flagged as 
  edited and belong to @user. 1 SQL query.
```

Essentially each named scope creates an SQL fragment. Rails will skillfully merge with every other SQL fragment in the chain to produce a single query returing exactly what you want. The methods added by the association methods work the same way. Which is why they seamlessly integrate with named_scopes.

The reason for the mix & match didn't work is the same that the of_sector method defined in the question doeso't work. edited_methods returns an Array, where as edited_scope (as well as find and all other AR convenience methods called as part of a chain) pass their SQL fragment onward to the next thing in the chain. If it's the last in the chain it executes the query. Similarly, this won't work either.

```
@edited = Article.edited_scope
@edited.recent_scope
```

You tried to use this code. Here's the proper way to do it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles do
     def of_sector(sector_id)
       find(:all, :conditions => {:sector_id => sector_id})
     end
   end
end
```

To achieve this functionality you want to do this:

```
class Articles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  named_scope :of_sector, lambda do |*sectors|
    { :conditions => {:sector_id => sectors} }
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
@user.articles.of_sector(4) 
=>    # articles belonging to @user and sector of 4
@user.articles.of_sector(5,6) 
=>    # articles belonging to @user and either sector 4 or 5
@user.articles.of_sector([1,2,3,]) 
=>    # articles belonging to @user and either sector 1,2, or 3
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question.  This explains how to use associations and named scopes, but doesn't explain how they actually work.  See my answer for that.

Comment: Rails doesn't actually know what "the last [scope] in the chain" is. In fact, no named scopes actually execute any SQL calls. It's only when you *do* something with the scope (for example .each if iterating, or .to_s as `puts` implicitely does) that the database it queried.

Answer (score 1):

As metioned previously, when doing

```
@user.articles.class
=> Array
```

what you actually get is Array. That is because #class method was undefined, as also mentioned before.

But how do you get the actual class of @user.articles (which should be proxy)?

```
Object.instance_method(:class).bind(@user.articles).call
=> ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
```

And why did you get Array in the first place? Because #class method was delegated to CollectionProxy @target instance through method missin, which is actually an array.
You could peek behind the scene by doing something like this:

```
@user.articles.proxy_association
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do an association (`has_one`, `has_many`, etc.), it tells the model to include some methods automatically by ActiveRecord. However, when you decided to create an instance method returning the association yourself, you won't be able to make use of those methods.

The sequence is something like this

1. setup `articles` in `User` model, i.e. do a `has_many :articles`
2. ActiveRecord automatically includes convenient methods into model (e.g. `size`, `empty?`, `find`, `all`, `first`, etc)
3. setup `user` in `Article`, i.e. do a `belongs_to :user`
4. ActiveRecord automatically includes convenient methods into model (e.g. `user=`, etc)

Thus, it's clear that when you declare an association, the methods are added automatically by ActiveRecord, which is the beauty as it handled a tremendous amount of work, which will need to be done manually otherwise =)

you can read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

hope this helps =)

Comment: This I knew. But my question is, if at all I were to implement what AR does for me, how would I add those size, empty?, find, all, first etc methods to the array of returned objects. Also, I wanted the sequence in which @user.articles.find(:all, :conditions => {:sector_id => 3}) would get executed. Are the conditions applied before fetching the association objects? Or are all the association objects fetched first and re-queried by applying the conditions on limited set of objects?

Comment: The main model, in your case, user, is fetched first (even with the case of usign :include). and subsequent queries using user.articles.find are issued thereafter, adding the user_id (since ar already know which user_id to use). You can try it by looking at the log file, by doing:

user.find(1)
user.articles.find(1)

and check what sql queries are issued =)

i don't understand why you would want to implement your own though... unless you are trying to do the same thing with other frameworks and you just want to know how ar does it...

Comment: well, then i hope the rubyonrails guide helps =)

Comment: This explains what the has_many/belongs_to class macros do, but not how the actual association proxy works.  Chirantan, it works the other way.  @user.articles does not really return an Array, even though if you call `class` on it, it returns Array.  As Chad Fowler likes to say, it's lying to you. :)  See my answer for the details on how an AssocationProxy masquerades as an Array.