# has_many returns an array instead of ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, railscasts

I am following [OmniAuth railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) and trying to implement the same with authlogic + facebook instead of devise + twitter as shown in the railscast.

Maybe my understanding of `has_many` still isn't good but in the railscasts ryan has the [following code](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-235/todo/app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb) in `AuthenticationsController`

```
  def create
    auth = request.env["rack.auth"]
    current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    redirect_to authentications_url
  end
```

In my implementation `current_user.authentications` returns an array `[]` how can I call `find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid` on an array?

Is my implementation wrong? Isn't `has_many` suppose to return an array?

Error I get is that I am calling `find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid` on a `nil` object.

`current_user.authentications` is nil well because the user does not have any authentications yet.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Rails 3, or are you using an earlier version of Rails?

Comment: positive about it being rails 3. had this problem last night, thought I'll ask here before I tackle with it again at home.  Perhaps there is something wrong in my source. but shouldn't `has_many` bring back an array?

Comment: It appears to me that what you have coded should work. Have you verified that you aren't overriding the authentications relation with a function of your own (for example in the User class or in a related module)? Without seeing more code this is really all I can think of.

Comment: I understand. I'll go home and take a closer look. if not, will try to clone ryans github repo for this episode.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? All of my hm:t relationships inexplicably started returning Arrays instead of ActiveRecord::Relations today. I've tried multiple versions of rails 3, and many different hm:t relationships on many different models. All of them return Arrays. Very inconvenient!

Answer (score 5):

The array is actually an `AssociationProxy` instance, which delegates all method calls to the internal object, which is an array in the case of a `has_many` association (also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529606/how-do-rails-association-methods-work)). This means you should be able to call magic methods like `find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid`, as well as scopes etc. on it just fine.

I found this question because I stumbled over a similar problem: for some reason I couldn't call `ActiveRecord::Relation#klass` to find out the model class:

```
post.comments.klass # => NoMethodError
```

But by calling `relation` first you can get a normal `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance:

```
post.comments.relation.klass # => Comment
```