# ActiveRecord::Relation mystery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Please explain why:

```
User.first.comments.class => Array
User.first.comments.missing_method => undefined method `missing_method' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Why in the first line class is Array and the other is Relation?

Answer (score 1):

`User.first.comments` actually returns an AssociationProxy object. You're getting an Array when you call `User.first.comments.class` because the `class` method is undefined and being delegated elsewhere.

Check out [How do rails association methods work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529606/how-do-rails-association-methods-work)

Comment: Looks like your're right
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy

Answer (score 0):

Because method User.first.comments exist and it has return value array and missing_method doesn't exist for Relation comments. comments is ActiveRecord::Relation method with return value array.

Comment: You say that method comments returns Array so why when I call some method on Array it goes to Relation?

Comment: Because comments is relation class, if you call it alone "User.first.comments" it run method which return array, but if you call array's method on comments, comments is Array class.