# Rails Associations push (collection<<)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, rails-activerecord

Does pushing an entity to a it's parent collection causes the collection to be loaded?

e.g.:

```
Parent.childs << a_child
```

Is the parent.childs "array" now loaded with ALL the childs or just "a_child" ?  i.e. will a SQL "select * from childs where parent_id = ?" statement will be executed before adding to the collection?

EDIT:

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionAssociation/concat_records seems to call "add_target" BEFORE calling "insert_record" which adds the entity to the @target array...

Comment: You can try this out in your Rails console (`rails console`, or `rails c` for short) and see what SQL gets generated.

Comment: By the way, it is ```children```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (thank god)! `Parent.childs` is a Proxy and '<<' will just trigger the creation/update of `a_child`

More info on [How do rails association methods work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529606/how-do-rails-association-methods-work)

Also in the rails comments of associations/collection_associations.rb

> You need to be careful with assumptions regarding the target: The
>   proxy does not fetch records from the database until it needs them,
>   but new ones created with +build+ are added to the target. So, the
>   target may be non-empty and still lack children waiting to be read
>   from the database. If you look directly to the database you cannot
>   assume that's the entire collection because new records may have been
>   added to the target, etc.

A quick check on my console confirmed there the children aren't loaded.

```
parent.children << child; nil
```

=> only parent and child where loaded....

Comment: Hum maybe my question was not clear because i already know that.  Please refer to my latest edit. TYVM.