# Rails: How To Track Down A Method Called On An Array That Has No Such Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, call

I'm trying to figure out something in a Rails application.  We have a class Site that has themes (of class Theme) and when a site uploads a theme it can install it for a specific site.  So I'm tracking down the code for that and I see it calls the method 'build' like this:

```
@theme = @current_site.themes.build(params[:theme])
```

the themes method simply returns an array of Theme objects associated with that site.  So in the rails console I tried this (result included):

```
>> site.themes.method(:build).__file__
NameError: undefined method `build' for class `Array'
```

and then I tried this:

```
>> site.themes.respond_to? :build
=> true
```

So my question is twofold, how can I find out where 'build' is defined so I can understand how it works?, and can someone explain to me how a method like 'build' works in terms of it being able to be called at the end of an Array object that has no such method?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your `Site` model `has_many :themes`, this is one of the association methods that automatically gets added to it by the association.

If you want some more reading material, check out the [Association Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (for example, the section on [`has_many` associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference)), this lists all of the methods added along with the parameters they take.

As to the exactly how this works, the `.themes` object is actually an `AssociationProxy` ([source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb)), with an `Array` as its target, not an `Array` itself. `.class` returns `'Array'` because the proxy itself does not respond to the `.class` method, and instead forwards it to its target (the `Array`) via `method_missing`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529606/how-do-rails-association-methods-work#1554925) gives a more detailed explanation.