# Many-to-many associations in a single model (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

Lets say I have the following table of Users

id,   type
 1,    "A"
 2,    "B"
 3,    "B"
 4,    "A"
 5,    "B"
 6,    "A"

There are two user types. "A" users, and "B" users. "A"s can be connected to many "B"s, and "B"s can be connected to many "A"s. Let's say we have the following 'connections' table

id,   A_id,   B_id

1,    1,      2
 2,    4,      2
 3,    4,      3
 4,    6,      5
 5,    1,     5
 6,    4,      5

Which would represent the following graph:

[connections graph](http://i41.tinypic.com/az0q9.png)

I could have an "A"s table that stores the foreign_key indexes of the users with the "A" type (i.e. 'these users are type "A"), and similarly for "B", in which case I could just define a simple has_many association through the connections table from "A" to "B" and vice versa.

I want to be able to type something like a.b to produce all the "B" that the 'a' is connected to, as well as b.a to produce all the "A" that the 'b' is connected to.

My question is: can this many-to-many association between "A" and "B" be defined using a single User model instead? Can a self-join be used?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) go in the direction you're looking for? If not, what could serve as a real-world example for your model object and the relationships between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do rails association methods work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529606/how-do-rails-association-methods-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a pretty standard example of `has_many :through` and `STI`.

Given:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :connections do |t|
      t.integer :a_user_id
      t.integer :b_user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AUser < User
  has_many :connections
  has_many :b_users, :through => :connections
end

class BUser < User
  has_many :connections
  has_many :a_users, :through => :connections
end

class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a_user
  belongs_to :b_user
end
```

When (rails console output snipped for brevity):

```
>> a_user = AUser.create!
>> b_user = BUser.create!
>> connection = a_user.connections.build
>> connection.b_user = b_user
>> connection.save!
```

Then:

```
>> a_user.b_users
=> ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy of BUsers
```

If your `AUser` and `BUser` objects will have different sets of attributes then you should use [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) instead, which requires creating a couple more tables but really doesn't complicate things much.